# Reporting visibility on a custom child object

Tags: reporting, custom-object, sharing, campaign

I have a head scratcher of a problem. I created a custom object called Event Sales Activity which is child to Campaigns. I added lookups to Lead and Contact to the ESA Object. I've populated the object with some testing data. I can see all of the ESA records in a List View.

When I try to report on the object, I can see records on:

Campaign and ESA
Campaign and Lead
Campaign and Contact

But I can't see records in the following reports:
Leads and ESA
Contacts and ESA
Campaigns with ESA and Lead
Campaigns with ESA and Contact

I've checked the sharing settings. There Campaigns are set to public full access at the moment. Event Sales Activity is Controlled by Parent. Lead is Public Read Write. Contact at the moment is Private. All records are owned by me (it's a sandbox ).

I'm completely flummoxed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have to [create a custom report type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm&type=0):

select `Campaign` as a Primary Object, then `ESA Object`, and `Lead` at the end. Do the same for `Contact`